# How do I export as an .x file, without being saved as a text file?

Tags: export, file-format

How do I export as an .x file, without being saved as a text file?.

Answer (score 1):

.x is a depreciated format. Blender 2.8+ does not have any plug-in support, as .fbx is now the preferred format.There is an add-on for 2.70 you can enable (called DirectX X Format exporter I think) that should allow you to export to .x.